# Starting with Spark Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, npm, laravel-spark

I'm trying Spark and, after install it, I have two problems:

1.- When I try 'Log in' and 'Register' buttons, I get this. It is like if my web page with no style. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

2.- On the other hand, I'm following the Quickstart guide and I'm trying this:

> "Once Spark is installed, make sure the NPM dependencies have been
>   installed via the npm install command, the gulp command has been
>   executed, and the database migrations have ran."

I'm running `npm install` in my Terminal and I'm getting this: `-bash: npm: command not found`.

I did some things with Laravel more than one year ago, and it was with no Homestead. Probably I'm doing something wrong... I'm pretty confusing.

Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: Just to be sure, which Spark are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install node and npm:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node

Once node is up and running you should be able to run "gulp" from within your application's main folder. This will generate (among other things) the CSS that you're currently missing.